# Java не находит файл из-за кириллицы в пути

Tags: java, кодировка, input, path, resources

Пытаюсь динамически получить путь к файлу `mail.properties` при помощи конструкции:

```
this.mailPropsReader = new FileInputStream(MailSender.class.getResource("/mail.properties").getFile());
```

В ходе выполнения программы возникает ошибка следующего содержания:

```
a.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\%d0%95%d0%b2%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9\IdeaProjects\Mail_Sender\target\classes\mail.properties (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
```

А вся соль собственно в том, что у меня имя пользователя `Евгений` кириллицей. Если заменить `%d0%95%d0%b2%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9` на `Евгений`, то проводник прекрасно находит нужный файл. Я так понимаю, проблема в кодировке. Переименовывать пользователя не очень хочется (к тому же я уверен, что есть способы решить это проблему).

Как сделать так, чтобы корректно указывалась кириллица в пути к файлу?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617764/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-url-java

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование кириллицы в URL (Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617764/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-url-java)

Comment: По ссылке указано, как делать URL. Собственно, проблема которая возникала у того человека, у меня сама собой решилась (кириллица у меня как раз указывалась в нужном для url формате, а нужно было, чтобы она оставалась как и была, в виде слова).

Comment: По ссылке решается проблема, как сделать из кириллицы в URL удобоваримый utf-8.
У меня обратная проблема. Мне нужен не URL, а путь в файловой системе. И вот он как раз создаётся с преобразованием кириллицы в utf-8, а мне нужна кириллица в первоначальном виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я смог решить проблему изменив

```
this.mailPropsReader = new FileInputStream(MailSender.class.getResource("/mail.properties").getFile());
```

на

```
Path pathToRes = Paths.get(MailSender.class.getResource("/mail.properties").toURI());
this.mailPropsReader = new FileInputStream(pathToRes.toFile());
```

Теперь всё читается корректно, кириллица остаётся в пути в первоначальном виде.